# C++ winapi32 chart

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, bgi

I would like to create a chart with this tool: http://www.codecutter.net/tools/koolplot/

I use eclipse + minGW

I installed the koolplot, in this way:

```
Library installation for MingW: 
Copy headers koolplot.h, Plotdata.h, Plotstream.h, winbgitypes.h and BGI_util.h To your MingW #include directory.
Copy library libkoolplot.a to your MingW lib directory.
```

But first of all I had to modify the graphics.h file, after that I get this error:

```
g++ -mwindows -o aplot.exe -lkoolplot -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -o plot.exe "src\\plot.o" 
src\plot.o: In function `main':
...workspace\plot\Debug/../src/plot.cpp:5: undefined reference to `Plotdata::Plotdata(double, double)'
...plot\Debug/../src/plot.cpp:5: undefined reference to `operator*(double, Plotdata const&)'
...plot\Debug/../src/plot.cpp:5: undefined reference to `sin(Plotdata const&)'
...plot\Debug/../src/plot.cpp:5: undefined reference to `Plotdata::operator-(Plotdata const&) const'
...plot\Debug/../src/plot.cpp:6: undefined reference to `plot(Plotdata const&, Plotdata const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code:

```
#include "koolplot.h"
int main()
{
   plotdata x(-6.0, 6.0);
   plotdata y = sin(x) + x/5;
   plot(x, y);
   return 0;
}
```

Any idea whats wrong? 
Or could anybody send me another good (easy to use) tool to create charts?

Comment: sorry, I modified the post

Comment: `plotdata` should be `Plotdata`

Comment: I tried, but I got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **never** install any 3rd party libraries the way you just did. MinGW is a standalone toolchain and has to always stay virgin (untouched). You should have created a specific directory somewhere on your machine, lets say `koolplot`. Then create two more directories inside it `include` and `lib`. Then put headers in `include` and libraries in `lib`.

The next thing you should do is to add a path to includes and a path to libraries (the ones we've just created) for your project in Eclipse. Look carefully in the configuration of your project, there are special options dedicated to that.

If that still does not work, then I'll need more information:

1. With which compiler `koolplot` was built and what was a target platform?
2. What is the target platform of your current MinGW distribution as well?

**NOTE**: If you want to develop contemporary, good-looking, and cross-platform application, utilizing all the power of C++ object-oriented approach, then I'd highly recommend you to dive into [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). Yes, it contains widgets for charts, graphs, and much more stuff that you are probably even not aware of yet, but will surely need as your application grows.